# Insert data in MSSQL (with Python) does not work

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm running this code in Python:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server="IPHONEDEROMAIN", user="test", password="test",
                       database='db_test', autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.RECEVEUR ([NEFG_R], [sexe]) values (?, ?);",
               (30, "M"))
```

and i have an error even though I have the same code as all the tutorials and documentations I've found. I've tried taking the parenthesis around 30 and M off but I still have an error (arguments expected 2, arguments given 3).

```
pymssql._pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near '?'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Is there something I haven't seen?

Is this because I'm using Python 3.10.2? The posts I've seen on stackoverflow are very old (2018-2019)

Comment: 1. [The Pymssql Project was Discontinued in November 2019](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668) and so it is recommended you use a different library. 2. Pymssql doesn't use `?` for parameter markers, so if you *are* following documentation it isn't [Pymssql's](https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate_1_x_to_2_x.html#parameter-substitution).

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right. Thank you! It's resolved then I guess

Answer (score -1):

Try using "triple quotes" for your query.

For example, in my queries when connecting to MySQL using python I've used:

```
cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM test """)
```

Comment: I have just tried cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dbo.RECEVEUR ([NEFG_R], [sexe]) values (?, ?);""", (30, "M")) and unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: While this is a good idea (as you can use multiline strings) it isn't relevant